# javascript input and checking math function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, input

```
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
<p id="text"></p>
<script>
var input = document.getElementById("searchTxt");
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = input.value;</script>
```

I'm typing in the input and the text should appear below,but it doesn't and I dont know why, does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Your script is running when the page is loaded, not when the user types into the search field.

Comment: What does "checking math function" have to do with this question? There's no math anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the script when the user types into the field, you need to put it into an event listener. Your code is just running once, when the page is first loaded. Since nothing has been entered into the text field yet, nothing is put into the `innerHTML`.

```js
document.getElementById("searchTxt").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" />
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach the [oninput](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event handler to the input element like this:

```
var input = document.getElementById("searchTxt");

input.oninput = function() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = input.value;    
}

input.onpropertychange = input.oninput; // for IE8 and below
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yvu24jc/)